# What is the motivation of the identity $x\circ(a\circ b)=(((x\circ b)\circ a )\circ b$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, motivation

A *symmetric set* (also called an involutary quandle or a kei) is a set $A$ with a binary operation $\circ$ satisfying the following conditions for all $a,b,x\in A$:

1. $a\circ a =a$;
2. $(x\circ a)\circ a=x$;
3. $x\circ(a\circ b)=(((x\circ b)\circ a )\circ b$.

See [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ojm/1200769521) for further details. Now my question is about the motivation of the last identity $$x\circ(a\circ b)=(((x\circ b)\circ a )\circ b.$$
What are some familiar binary operations that satisfy this identity?

Comment: As far as I know, quandles were developed to solve the set-theoretic Yang-Baxter equation. It may be useful to look at papers involving such objects, since they usually come with motivating examples.

Comment: I think one example of such operation $x\circ y$ is some variant of the usual action by conjugation, so something like $x\circ y = xyx^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PedroTamaroff, I have checked the conjugation operation but it does not satisfy the third condition in general, except for a group in which the square of every element is in the centre.

Comment: Yes, what I wrote definitely *does not* work. I just meant to point to something.

Comment: Well, the paper you linked mentions several ways to get examples related to groups.

Answer (score 2):

One motivating example is the operation $x\circ a=ax^{-1}a$ on any group.  In particular, when the group in question is $\mathbb{R}^n$, this operation $x\circ a=2a-x$ has a geometric interpretation: it is the "reflection of $x$ across $a$" (that is, $-\circ a$ is the negation map when you consider the point $a$ to be the origin).  This geometric description can be generalized to make any [symmetric space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space) into a symmetric set, which I believe is the origin of the term "symmetric set".

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Your example satisfies the second condition $(x\circ a)\circ a=x$ as well. Since the second condition is independent of the third, do you happen to know any example that satisfies the third condition but not the second?

Comment: As far as I know the third condition is not of any interest on its own.

Comment: Thanks! Am curious why did somebody come up with the third equation in the first place... If it were replaced by a (non equivalent) equation $(x\circ y)\circ z=(x\circ z)\circ(y\circ z) $, I can see some connection to the Reidemeister Move III in knot theory; but am not sure about the third identity in my post.

Comment: I imagine they were trying to axiomatize the symmetry operations on a symmetric space.

Comment: Thank you again! I am hoping for an example showing that condition 2 and condition 3 are independent; that is a set that satisfies 3 but not 2.

Comment: Well, if you don't care about condition 1, a trivial way to satisfy condition 3 without condition 2 is to have $x\circ a=c$ for all $x,a$, for some fixed element $c$.  If you want condition 1 as well, you can just define $x\circ a=c$ if $x\neq a$ and $a\circ a=a$.

Comment: @Zuriel, (3) **is** equivalent to the self-distributive axiom $(xy)z = (xz)(yz)$ [SD] in the presence of (2): [3 => SD] $(xz)(yz) =_3 (((xz)z)y)z) =_2 (xy)z$ and [SD => 3] $((xb)a)b =_{SD} ((xb)b)(ab) =_2 x(ab)$. (Hope clear enough without the $\circ$ symbols, they take a while to type...)